# java regular expression

Tags: java, regex

How do I match a file name that does not end with a hyphen, using Java?

Comment: 0_o. I have no clue what that means.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "file name"? Do you just mean the name without extension (i.e. you would match `foo.txt` but not `foo-.txt`)? Or do you include the extension (i.e. you would match `foo-.txt` but not `foo.txt-`)? You need to give us a list of filenames that you would expect to match and a list of ones that wouldn't match.

Comment: ¿Can you provide any context? Are you talking about regular expressions, or just inspect the file name (a string) and look for determinate characters, or using a JFileChooser and need to use a FileFilter, or listing files in a directory with File.list() and need to use a FilenameFilter...

Comment: implementing spring integration directory scanner based on file name (inc. ext) pattern. Plan to use RegexFileFiler (apache). The expected default behaviour would be to return files not ending with hyphen unless a regex is supplied. example a.xml and a.txt1 is returned from the list of a.xml, a.xml-, a.txt1

Answer (score 3):

If you really, really need the regexp, this should do: `.+[^-]` (at least one character (any) followed by anything BUT hypen). It can be as complicated as you want to check for possible border cases, if needed.

Comment: That one will not work. The regex engine will simply backtrack one char and match everything up to the dash. If the string consists of just the filename, then adding a `$` to the end of the expression would make it work. i.e. `^.+[^-]$`.

Comment: If the filename ends with a dash, the regexp matching will fail as the dash is matched by the `.+` part and there are no more chars to match the `[^-]` part. Adding `^` and `$` won't hurt, though.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you need a regex for that? Especially in Java. You can just check whether a hyphen is the last character of the filename.

Comment: sure. but i need a regex pattern implementation to make the filter rule generic. dont want to do start with or end with like..

Answer (score 0):

Try (any character at least one time plus the last one any character except '-'):

`.+[^-]`